# How to use Particle Swarm Optimization as a Search Space Optimizer

Tags: python, search, optimization, space, particle-swarm

I have two problems regarding PSO;

(1). I have a problem in which I need to find the optimal or nearly optimal set of solutions.  So PSO should work as an optimizer rather than being a function minimizer. 
 (2). As the fitness function, what I have is a set of parameters that hold values either 1 or zero(binary parameters). Therefore to obtain the parameter values,I have to run an outside boolean function which checks against some empirical rules.

So how to write a rule based fitness function for PSO?

Guys, 
Please help me. If you happen to know any method/implementation, pl let me know.

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT**:
So sorry sir. This is my first time asking a question. Let me rephrase the question again.
Here's what I need to do. I have a set of candidate solutions, each have several properties. Now I need to use PSO to select the best/optimal solution out from that set. Here I do have 9 parameters  which can be used to check whether each particle suffice all those conditions. 
the specialty in those parameters is they have their own range to accept a candidate solution as a optimal one. Here's example of a fitness function and parameters:

```
fitness=(4*weight+ 3.75*length + 9*pressure .....)
```

where:

```
weight: "1" if it's in the range (20-30), else "0"
length: "1" if it's below 85, else "0"
pressure: "1" if it's greater than 125, else "0"
```

**Note**: a particle having length as 60 is better than a particle of length 84 and a particle having pressure as 200 is better than a particle with pressure 126

Comment: Optimization and minimization are essentially the same thing. Your question should be more specific. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/about and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: So sorry sir, Please check the question again. I've rephrased the question(Under EDIT)

Comment: You can't just post your homework problem. You need to explain what you have tried and what you are having difficulties with. For example, are you having difficulty writing the function to minimize? See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18242/what-is-the-policy-here-on-homework (specifically answer by OwenP).